# angularjs - ngpattern and custom validation is both displayed

Tags: angularjs, validation, custom-validators

I have a min and max directive that I've created which checks if an input is between a range. I also have an ng-pattern validation. I'm using ng-messages to display my validation. I have an issue where even though user has entered in the correct pattern, the validation message for "pattern" is still displaying. I only would like to display the validation that the range is outside the range. Here is the html

```
 <form name="fee">

  <input type="text" name="fee_classi" ng-model="main.fee.I"
  ng-pattern="/^[0-1](\.\d{0,2}){0,1}$/" 
  my-range="1,1.75"/>

  <div role="alert" class="validation-errors" 
  ng-if="fee.fee_classi.$invalid && fee.fee_classi.$dirty"
  ng-messages="fee.fee_classi.$error">
    <p ng-message="range">Range should be between 1 to 1.75</p>
    <p ng-message="pattern">Format must be 0.00</p>

  </div>
</form>
```

Here is the directive

```
app.directive('myRange', myRange);

function myRange() {
  var directive = {
    bindToController: true,
    controller: myRangeCtrl,
    controllerAs: 'vm',
    // link: link,
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {},
    require: {
      ngModelCtrl: 'ngModel'
    }
  };
  return directive;
}

myRangeCtrl.$inject = ['$element', '$attrs'];

function myRangeCtrl($element, $attrs) {
  var vm = this;

  vm.min = 0; //default
  vm.max = 0; //default

  console.clear();
  console.log(vm.ngModelCtrl);
  var inRange = false;
  var rangeVal = $attrs.myRange.split(',');
  var userInput;
  console.log(rangeVal);
  vm.min = JSON.parse(rangeVal[0]);

  vm.max = JSON.parse(rangeVal[1]);


  $element.on('keypress', function(e) {
    console.log(e);
    console.log(vm.ngModelCtrl);

    //if the pattern is valid then lets check if the user has the proper range
    if (vm.ngModelCtrl.$valid) {
      vm.ngModelCtrl.$validators.range = function(modelValue, viewValue) {

        console.log('modelValue = ' + modelValue);

        inRange = _.inRange(modelValue, vm.min, vm.max);

        //check if modelValue can be converted to a number with isNaN function
        if (isNaN(modelValue)) {
          console.error('-VAlue is invalid');
          return false;
        }

        if (angular.isDefined(modelValue) &&
          modelValue[modelValue.length - 1] !== '.' &&
          modelValue !== '') {
          // console.log('modelValue = '+modelValue);
          userInput = JSON.parse(modelValue);

          if (inRange || userInput === vm.max) {
            console.info('VAlue is valid');
            //value entered is invalid
            return true;
          } else {
            console.error('VAlue is invalid');
            //value entered is valid
            return false;
          }
        }

        if (angular.isUndefined(modelValue)) {
          return true;
        }
        //lets do a regex test first


      };

    }

  });
```

Here is the [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/rsGe9T31TV70t59i4ptA?p=preview)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Look at this example: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Brange%5D
You may need to tweak it a bit to fit for your need.